# Automatically set command for each capital letter in `\mathsf`, `\mathbb`, and `\mathcal`

Tags: fonts, macros, math-fonts

I typically create new commands for every capital letter in `\mathsf`, `\mathbb`, and `\mathcal`.

```
# Sans-serif capital letters
\newcommand{\Asf}{\mathsf{A}}
\newcommand{\Bsf}{\mathsf{B}}
.
.
.
\newcommand}{\Zsf}{\mathsf{Z}}

# Bold math capital letters
\newcommand{\Abb}{\mathbb{A}}
\newcommand{\Bbb}{\mathbb{B}}
.
.
.
\newcommand{\Zbb}{\mathbb{Z}}
```

Is it possible to do this automatically in a for loop?

Comment: yes you could but is `\Abb` really easier than `\mathbb A` or (even) `\bb A` which just needs `\let\bb\mathbb`

Comment: Maybe you need an editor with better autocomplete …

Comment: @cabohah maybe I do.. I am using overleaf at the moment

Comment: Related: [Help on an expl3 command for building shortcuts for math macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/632777/5764)

Comment: don't you get an error for `\newcommand{\Bbb}{\mathbb{B}}` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Remember, this is Overleaf. So error reporting is somewhat hidden.

Comment: only if you ignore big red circles with an error count. @Werner

Comment: I added a more general method tailored for your case at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/564222/4427

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I do get an error for it, seems like it's already defined. Is it an important variable?

Comment: never ignore errors, after _any_ error if you scroll past it, any generated pdf is at best a debugging aid, not usable. `\Bbb` is an old command to access blackboard bold, kept for compatibility, if you redefine it you break any code (perhaps in a package) that is using it, so it is up to you to check, I can't tell you if it breaks anything in your document @Physics_Student

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't do this but

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\let\Bbb\relax% sigh
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_map_inline:nn
{sf,bb,cal}
{\int_step_inline:nnn {`A} {`Z} 
{
\cs_new:cpn{
  \char_generate:nn{##1}{12}#1}{\cs:w math#1\cs_end
                                              {\char_generate:nn{##1}{12}}}}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

$ \Qbb + \Zsf $

\end{document}
```